# ExoPlayer Audio capture for visualiser

Tags: audio, capture, exoplayer

I am trying to understand how to capture the audio to render a waveform on an OpenGL canvas for exoplayer.

It seems possible to implement by extending the
MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer class as it has a processOutputBuffer() method.

Can anybody advise or point me to an example of how this can be implemented?

Comment: do you get any solution for your problem